# Prove sets equality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $A = B = C$ if the following relations hold:

1. $A \cup B = C$
2. $(A \cup C) \cap B = C$
3. $(A \cap C) \cup B = A$

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$A\cup B= C \tag 1$$ you obtain from the third that $$A=(A\cap C)\cup B= (A\cup B) \cap (C\cup B)\overset{(1)}= C \cap (C\cup B)=C$$ Now, rewrite the second with $A=C$ to get $$C=(C\cup C)\cap B= C\cap B\overset{(1)}=B$$

Comment: why do you need `(2)` if you have `(1)`? Or should `(1)` have a union symbol instead of a comma?

Comment: @Brian J. Yes, you are right, it was a typo. (2) is the reverse inclusion. And (1) is correct as it with a comma.

Comment: @BrianJ So, I corrected what you said, is it ok now?

Comment: I'm now not sure how you come to the conclusion of `(2)`, but there's probably a property of sets that I'm forgetting. It looks to me like it still should be $A \subseteq C$. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @BrianJ Funny thing, you were right all the time, that my answer was wrong. And it was upvoted and accepted and no one else noticed... I think now it is correct. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Not a problem. I think it looks correct now to me as well. +1

Answer (score 6):

The first equation implies $A,B \subseteq C$. The second equation implies $C \subseteq B$ and hence $B=C$. The third equation implies $B \subseteq A$ and with $B=C$ and $A \subseteq C$ it follows $A=B=C$.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that, using 3. in 1., you get $C=A$:
$$
C=A\cup B=((A\cap C)\cup B)\cup B=(A\cap C)\cup B=A.
$$
Then, by 3. and $A=C$, you have that 
$$
A=(A\cap C)\cup B=A\cup B,
$$
Thus $B\subseteq A$. Finally, by 2. and $A=C$, you have:
$$
A=C=(A\cup C)\cap B=A\cap B,
$$
so that $A\subseteq B$.